# How extract my base name with a str_detect?

Tags: r

I have a string that is the path from my directory to the base that I am using. I need to apply a str_detect to it so that it returns only the base name, but without specifying what the base name is.
That is, if I have this path: "Data/Bases/Canonical/ListData-entry2018.xls" I need ListData-entry2018 to return How can it be done without specifying the name? Thank you very much.

Comment: you are looking for the function `basename()` ? Or else a regex that strips all before the last `/` and after the `.` ?

Comment: As a new contributor, please participate and do respond to the inputs from SO and accept / upvote answers provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to use only "str_detect"? as suggested by @Quinten basename("path from my directory") will give you desired name "but with extension".
Keeping things simple, you can use regex or extract string from the matched string.
Lets try few methods :

### 1st and best

The best is to use tools package with built-in function to get filename withotu extension. In your case you can combine it with basename() if you have only strings in your data.

You can combine them in 1 line or function()

```
p <- "Data/Bases/Canonical/ListData-entry2018.xls"
p_base <- basename(p)
file_path_sans_ext(p_base)
```

If you have working directory, then `list.files()` will give you file names in a vector- check options- and you can apply above to each of them.

### 2nd

just use sub with pattern of matching the end part after . (denoted by $) (regex)

```
sub('\\..*$', '', basename(p))
```

### 3rd

since extensions are mostly 3 characters after dot ., another way is to use substr :

```
substr(p_base, 1, nchar(p_base)-4)
```

All these get

```
> file_path_sans_ext(p_base)
[1] "ListData-entry2018"
> sub('\\..*$', '', basename(p))
[1] "ListData-entry2018"
> substr(p_base, 1, nchar(p_base)-4)
[1] "ListData-entry2018"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but using `str_detect` to return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` of your basename using `basename` to your string can be done using this code:

```
string <- "Data/Bases/Canonical/ListData-entry2018.xls"
pattern = basename(string)

str_detect(string = string, pattern = pattern)
```

Output:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Which means it detected the specified string.

Comment: Thanks, but that give me "ListData-entry2018.xls" and I need ListData-entry2018. Without the .xls and the "